# Running Python Scripts in Mongoose

Tags: python, cgi, mongoose-web-server

I want to run python scripts on the mongoose web server. It worked fine with php-cgi.exe but not with python.exe.

Test script test.py:

```
print("Content-Type: text/html")
print("")
print("<h1>Hello World!</h1>")
```

Mongoose configuration mongoose.conf:

```
m .py=text/html
c py
I C:\\python\\python.exe
```

I've tried the script from the command prompt and it correctly returns:

```
Content-Type: text/html

<h1>Hello World!</h1>
```

Calling up http://localhost/test.py returns the following:

```
print("Content-Type: text/html")
print("")
print("<h1>Hello World!</h1>")
```

So the python code is not being interpreted and no errors are logged.

Comment: I've also tried I `C:\\python\\python.exe -u`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: the mongoose.conf file is case sensitive. The following line is incorrect:

`c py`

it should be

`C py`

I can also confirm it works without `#!python.exe` or `#!c:\python33\python.exe`. How? Maybe mongoose is hard-wired to run `python.exe` when it sees a `.py` file and `python.exe` is in my `PATH`.

Comment: _I can also confirm it works without #!python.exe or #!c:\python33\python.exe. How?_  
[From the docs](https://github.com/valenok/mongoose/blob/master/UserManual.md#cgi_interpreter)     
>> _Path to an executable to use as CGI interpreter for all CGI scripts regardless script extension. If this option is not set (which is a default), Mongoose looks at first line of a CGI script, shebang line), for an interpreter._

Comment: Yep, it's the cgi_interpreter parameter or: I C:\\python\\python.exe

Answer (score 2):

A simple mongoose.conf:

```
document_root d:\root
listening_ports 80
cgi_extensions .py
```

hello.py:

```
#!python.exe
print("Content-Type: text/html")
print("")
print("<h1>Hello World!</h1>")
```

Works fine on my win-machine with PYTHONPATH set.

P.S. Instead of the `#!python.exe` I could use something like `#!d:\python\python.exe` or `#!d:/python/python.exe` - it works either way.

Answer (score 1):

Update for mongoose 4.1, the config needs to be

```
cgi_pattern **.py$
cgi_interpreter C:\Python27\python.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Using mongoose-3.0, edit the mongoose configuration file `mongoose.conf` to include the lines

```
cgi_extensions .py
cgi_interpreter c:\python26\python.exe
```

and the python should execute and the html result should be displayed OK in the browser.

Running under windows 7, the OP's python code was placed in the file `test.py` and the url browsed was `http://localhost:82/test.py` based on my invoking mongoose with `mongoose-3.0.exe -p 82 -e error_mongoose.txt`.

Note that I did not need to have anything like `#!c:\\python26\\python.exe` in the first line of the python file.  There may be other ways of getting python invoked, but I didn't have much luck getting it to work by specifying the interpreter exe as a #! comment on the first line of the script.  I guess my solution is the next best thing - at least it works.